# jQuery + MVC + DateTime Format

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, masking, jquery-mask

In my aspx:

```
<td class="data"><%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastContainerStartDate)%></td>
```

where lastContainerStartDate is of dataType DateTime

and in

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#LastContainerSeqNum").numeric();
           $("#LastContainerStartDate").mask("99/99/9999 99:99:99");
           $("#LastContainerEndDate").mask("99/99/9999 99:99:99");
```

when the page get loads => only loads the date with full mask format

Ex:  10/01/2010 loads fine.
     01/01/2010 comes with blank field

How can i make my mask format for first char optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - I suggest that you add a tag to this post clarifying which plugin this involves, because .mask is not a native method for JQuery.

Second - could you please clarify your question?

> Ex: 10/01/2010 loads fine. 01/01/2010 comes with blank field

It seems that you are trying to input 01/01/2010, which should be legal input given that mask, and I was able to input that data, and retrieve it from the db (and populate correctly) in my own testing.

But then you ask:

> How can i make my mask format for
>   first char optional.

Could you specify what exactly you are looking for? Are you looking to make the input accept a string like 1/1/2010, or are you having problems making it accept the leading zero?

Comment: Hello Paula. Yes it is problem making it accept the leading zero. When it load record from database for 'Edit' => if date in database is 01/10/2010 => it doesn't load.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the plugin located at http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ ? I am using that version and have not encountered any issues with the leading zero. If you are using the latest version, then I suggest that you remove the mask and see if you are able to have a leading zero without it - that way you can figure out if this is an issue with the jquery plugin, or an issue with some other part of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for but I've found the below plugins quite satisfactory and useful.

[Input Mask](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/mask)

[jQuery Alphanumeric](http://www.itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/)